# When ListView HorizontalAlignment=Stretch it no longer scrolls?

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a WP WinRT app that contains a page with a ListView that needs to scroll if it's content (binding) is longer than the screen. Now I want this app to be scalable across different screensizes, but right now the scrollviewer just falls of the page, and does not snap to the bottom of the screen.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="100"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Title Panel -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="19,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="TITLE" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,12,-0.167,0">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource LightForegroundColor}"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="subtitle Margin="0,-6.5,0,26.5" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" CharacterSpacing="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" FontSize="48">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,18.833,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is a textblock with some random text." VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14.667" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource DarkForegroundColor}"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
        </TextBlock>

    </StackPanel>

        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <DataTemplate>

            <StackPanel Margin="0,11,0,0">
                <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" Text="Text"/>
            </StackPanel>

    </DataTemplate>

     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. The ListView you provided scrolls fine and takes up all the remaining vertical space. Could you please clarify your problem? What do you mean "the scrollviewer just falls of the page" (it doesn't) and "does not snap to the bottom of the screen" (it does).

Comment: VerticalScrollViewVisibility = Visible did the trick.